# What is the solution of this error in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core

This problem occurs while I am trying to connect to SQL Server. What is the solution?

[image: This problem occurs while I am trying to connect to SQL Server. What is the solution?]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and any error messages as text and not as an image.

Comment: You can share the code of `ApplicationDbContext` and the nuget packages you installed?Please provide a [minimal reproducible unit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `ApplicationDbContext` is not derived from `DbContext`, you must derive from `DbContext` as shown below, `I included namespace as well`;

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
{
   ...
}
```

**Note that** there is a hint at the end of the error message about which type you used and about what type is needed such as;

> The type 'ApplicationDbContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method ''. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ApplicationDbContext' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'.

Answer (score 0):

This method is called by the runtime. Use this method to add a DatabaseContext to the container:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {         
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });
    }
```